# number of participants to have a 80% chance of detecting a 1.5% point difference as significant

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, statistical-power

Can someone explain how the math used to determine that 34 participants were required for this study?

> *To have an 80% chance of detecting a 1.5–percentage point between-group A1C difference as significant (at the two-sided 5% level), with an assumed SD of 1.9% and a loss to follow-up of 26%, 34 participants were required per group. An interim analysis indicated group differences of 0.8% with an SD of 1.3%; therefore, a revised power analysis was conducted.*

[A Low-Fat Vegan Diet Improves Glycemic Control and Cardiovascular Risk Factors in a Randomized Clinical Trial in Individuals With Type 2 Diabetes.](http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/29/8/1777.full)

Comment: On the other hand, if this is in reference to a real study please offer a full reference (authors, year, title, journal, volume, page numbers if possible)

Comment: The note on "loss to follow-up" suggests that there may have been multiple blood samples from the same individuals or some test of a response to therapy, which would influence power calculations. One also worries sometimes when power analysis is "revised" during a study. A reference would help a lot.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Your link to the original paper helped clarify the potential ambiguity in the description contained in the quoted excerpt. This was a standard power analysis for what would effectively be a 2-sample *t*-test.

The design was to look at the *change* in A1C values (expressed in percentage points) in participants randomly assigned to one of two diets. For this analysis, those *changes* in A1C are the data being analyzed. The "assumed SD of 1.9%" was the anticipated standard deviation, in the percentage-point scale, among the individual *changes* within each diet group, perhaps based on prior studies.

The "1.5–percentage point between-group A1C difference" is the size of the difference in the changes between the two groups that they hoped to detect. For example, if diet 1 led to an average drop of 1 point in A1C, then they would want to say that a drop of 2.5 points with diet 2 was statistically different from the result with diet 1 at "the two-sided 5% level." That's the standard choice for the risk of "finding" a difference that isn't really there, called the Type I error.

The "80% chance of detecting" such a difference between the diets is also a standard choice. That means that the authors were willing to accept a 20% chance that they would not detect a true difference of that magnitude, the Type II error.

So the problem is to find how many cases in each group are needed to provide this tradeoff between falsely finding a difference and missing a true difference, based on the 1.5-point assumed difference (in A1C changes) between the groups and a 1.9-point standard deviation of the A1C changes within each group. That's a 2-sample *t*-test, for which the calculations are based on the (well known, at least to statisticians) non-central *t* distribution.

[This Cross Validated page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17042/28500) shows how the calculations can be done, with a diagram that I have copied here showing the tradeoff between Type I and Type II errors:

[image: power diagram]

For this case, use $\delta$ = 1.5, $\sigma$ = 1.9, $\alpha$ = 0.05, and $\beta$ = 0.2, with $n$ being the necessary size of each group. Standard statistical packages perform the calculations. I repeated this calculation with [Russ Lenth's Java applet](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/Power/) and found that you would need to end up with 26 cases in each group. The authors expected 26% of their participants to drop out of the study, so they needed to start with 34 in each group.

The complete experimental design was a good deal more complicated, with multiple measurements of weight, A1C, and other variables over the course of more than a year. As the authors note in your quoted excerpt, as the study proceeded they found that their initial estimates of both the inter-group difference and the within-group SDs were both too high, so they added more participants to obtain 80% power with their revised estimates. Some might find this change of study design in midstream to be less than ideal.